# What are proper bower dependencies for full fledged Polymer 2 application?

Tags: polymer-2.x

I have a finished Polymer 1 application that has not been released yet, so I decided to upgrade it to Polymer 2.
In bower dependencies I used to have

```
"polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^1.4.0",
"platinum-elements": "PolymerElements/platinum-elements#^2.0.0",
"paper-elements": "PolymerElements/paper-elements#^1.0.7",
"neon-elements": "PolymerElements/neon-elements#^1.0.0",
"iron-elements": "PolymerElements/iron-elements#^1.0.9",
"gold-elements": "PolymerElements/gold-elements#^1.0.1",
"app-route": "PolymerElements/app-route#^1.0.1",
```

Digging deep I discovered, that PolymerElements/paper-elements does not really pull down version 2 of elements.

So, now my bower looks like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^2.0.0",
    "webcomponentsjs": "webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#^1.0.0",
    "app-route": "PolymerElements/app-route#^2.0.0",
    "app-layout": "PolymerElements/app-layout#^2.0.0",
    "neon-animation": "PolymerElements/neon-animation#^2.0.0",
    "paper-badge": "PolymerElements/paper-badge#^2.0.0",
    "paper-behaviors": "PolymerElements/paper-behaviors#^2.0.0",
    "paper-button": "PolymerElements/paper-button#^2.0.0",
    "paper-card": "PolymerElements/paper-card#^2.0.0",
    "paper-checkbox": "PolymerElements/paper-checkbox#^2.0.0",
    "paper-dialog": "PolymerElements/paper-dialog#^2.0.0",
    "paper-dialog-behavior": "PolymerElements/paper-dialog-behavior#^2.0.0",
    "paper-dialog-scrollable": "PolymerElements/paper-dialog-scrollable#^2.0.0",
    "paper-dropdown-menu": "PolymerElements/paper-dropdown-menu#^2.0.0",
    "paper-fab": "PolymerElements/paper-fab#^2.0.0",
    "paper-header-panel": "PolymerElements/paper-header-panel#^2.0.0",
    "paper-icon-button": "PolymerElements/paper-icon-button#^2.0.0",
    "paper-input": "PolymerElements/paper-input#^2.0.0",
    "paper-item": "PolymerElements/paper-item#^2.0.0",
    "paper-listbox": "PolymerElements/paper-listbox#^2.0.0",
    "paper-menu-button": "PolymerElements/paper-menu-button#^2.0.0",
    "paper-progress": "PolymerElements/paper-progress#^2.0.0",
    "paper-radio-button": "PolymerElements/paper-radio-button#^2.0.0",
    "paper-radio-group": "PolymerElements/paper-radio-group#^2.0.0",
    "paper-ripple": "PolymerElements/paper-ripple#^2.0.0",
    "paper-slider": "PolymerElements/paper-slider#^2.0.0",
    "paper-spinner": "PolymerElements/paper-spinner#^2.0.0",
    "paper-styles": "PolymerElements/paper-styles#^2.0.0",
    "paper-swatch-picker": "PolymerElements/paper-swatch-picker#^2.0.0",
    "paper-tabs": "PolymerElements/paper-tabs#^2.0.0",
    "paper-toast": "PolymerElements/paper-toast#^2.0.0",
    "paper-toggle-button": "PolymerElements/paper-toggle-button#^2.0.0",
    "paper-tooltip": "PolymerElements/paper-tooltip#^2.0.0",
    "iron-a11y-announcer": "PolymerElements/iron-a11y-announcer#^2.0.0",
    "iron-a11y-keys": "PolymerElements/iron-a11y-keys#^2.0.0",
    "iron-a11y-keys-behavior": "PolymerElements/iron-a11y-keys-behavior#^2.0.0",
    "iron-ajax": "PolymerElements/iron-ajax#^2.0.0",
    "iron-autogrow-textarea": "PolymerElements/iron-autogrow-textarea#^2.0.0",
    "iron-behaviors": "PolymerElements/iron-behaviors#^2.0.0",
    "iron-collapse": "PolymerElements/iron-collapse#^2.0.0",
    "iron-component-page": "PolymerElements/iron-component-page#^2.0.0",
    "iron-demo-helpers": "PolymerElements/iron-demo-helpers#^2.0.0",
    "iron-doc-viewer": "PolymerElements/iron-doc-viewer#^2.0.0",
    "iron-dropdown": "PolymerElements/iron-dropdown#^2.0.0",
    "iron-fit-behavior": "PolymerElements/iron-fit-behavior#^2.0.0",
    "iron-flex-layout": "PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout#^2.0.0",
    "iron-icon": "PolymerElements/iron-icon#^2.0.0",
    "iron-icons": "PolymerElements/iron-icons#^2.0.0",
    "iron-iconset": "PolymerElements/iron-iconset#^2.0.0",
    "iron-iconset-svg": "PolymerElements/iron-iconset-svg#^2.0.0",
    "iron-image": "PolymerElements/iron-image#^2.0.0",
    "iron-jsonp-library": "PolymerElements/iron-jsonp-library#^2.0.0",
    "iron-list": "PolymerElements/iron-list#^2.0.0",
    "iron-location": "PolymerElements/iron-location#^2.0.0",
    "iron-media-query": "PolymerElements/iron-media-query#^2.0.0",
    "iron-overlay-behavior": "PolymerElements/iron-overlay-behavior#^2.0.0",
    "iron-pages": "PolymerElements/iron-pages#^2.0.0",
    "iron-swipeable-container": "PolymerElements/iron-swipeable-container#^1.0.3",
    "iron-checked-element-behavior": "PolymerElements/iron-checked-element-behavior#^2.0.0",
    "iron-form": "PolymerElements/iron-form#^2.0.0",
    "iron-form-element-behavior": "PolymerElements/iron-form-element-behavior#^2.0.0",
    "iron-input": "PolymerElements/iron-input#^2.0.0",
    "iron-label": "PolymerElements/iron-label#^2.0.0",
    "iron-localstorage": "PolymerElements/iron-localstorage#^2.0.0",
    "iron-menu-behavior": "PolymerElements/iron-menu-behavior#^2.0.0",
    "iron-meta": "PolymerElements/iron-meta#^2.0.0",
    "iron-range-behavior": "PolymerElements/iron-range-behavior#^2.0.0",
    "iron-resizable-behavior": "PolymerElements/iron-resizable-behavior#^2.0.0",
    "iron-scroll-target-behavior": "PolymerElements/iron-scroll-target-behavior#^2.0.0",
    "iron-scroll-threshold": "PolymerElements/iron-scroll-threshold#^2.0.0",
    "iron-selector": "PolymerElements/iron-selector#^2.0.0",
    "iron-test-helpers": "PolymerElements/iron-test-helpers#^2.0.0",
    "iron-validatable-behavior": "PolymerElements/iron-validatable-behavior#^2.0.0",
    "iron-validator-behavior": "PolymerElements/iron-validator-behavior#^2.0.0",
    "gold-elements": "PolymerElements/gold-elements#^1.0.1",
    "paper-date-picker": "polymer-paper-date-picker#^1.2.0",
    "paper-time-picker": "bendavis78/paper-time-picker#^1.1.4",
    "paper-password-input": "^2.1.0",
    "vaadin-upload": "^2.0.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.0.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.6.0"
  },
  "ignore": [],
  "resolutions": {
    "iron-a11y-announcer": "1 - 2",
    "webcomponentsjs": "^v1.0.0",
    "polymer": "^2.0.0",
    "iron-a11y-keys-behavior": "^2.0.0",
    "iron-autogrow-textarea": "1 - 2",
    "iron-collapse": "^2.0.0",
    "iron-behaviors": "^2.0.0",
    "iron-fit-behavior": "1 - 2",
    "iron-dropdown": "^2.0.0",
    "iron-flex-layout": "^2.0.0",
    "iron-icon": "1 - 2",
    "iron-iconset-svg": "1 - 2",
    "iron-image": "^2.0.0",
    "iron-media-query": "1 - 2",
    "iron-checked-element-behavior": "^2.0.0",
    "iron-list": "^2.0.0",
    "iron-overlay-behavior": "1 - 2",
    "iron-pages": "^2.0.0",
    "iron-form-element-behavior": "^2.0.0",
    "iron-input": "1 - 2",
    "iron-scroll-target-behavior": "^2.0.0",
    "iron-menu-behavior": "^2.0.0",
    "iron-range-behavior": "1 - 2",
    "iron-meta": "^2.0.0",
    "iron-resizable-behavior": "^2.0.0",
    "iron-selector": "^2.0.0",
    "iron-validator-behavior": "^2.0.0",
    "iron-validatable-behavior": "^2.0.0",
    "paper-button": "^2.0.0",
    "paper-icon-button": "^2.0.0",
    "paper-input": "^2.0.0",
    "paper-progress": "^2.0.0",
    "paper-ripple": "^2.0.0",
    "paper-styles": "^2.0.0",
    "paper-behaviors": "^2.0.0",
    "neon-animation": "^2.0.0"
  }
```

And I'm having whole bunch of problems.
Simple iron-form like this

```
    <iron-form id="loginForm">
        <form action="/" method="POST">
            <paper-input name="uid" label="Username" type="text" required auto-validate></paper-input>
            <paper-input name="pwd" label="Password" type="password" required auto-validate></paper-input>
            <paper-button class="primary" raised on-tap="_submit">Log in
                <button type="submit" class="no-style"></button>
            </paper-button>
        </form>
    </iron-form>
```

Where in my element I have

```
    _submit() {
        this.$.loginForm.submit();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        super.connectedCallback();
        this.$.loginForm.addEventListener('iron-form-presubmit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            myapp.auth.login(this.uid.value, this.pwd.value);
        });
    }
```

First, when I start typing username or password, the label will not float up and will show behind the username.

Second calling .submit() or .validate() on iron-form causes 'this.inputElement.validate is not a function' right here https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/blob/v2.0.1/paper-input-behavior.html#L437 and that's because this.inputElement is undefined.

Am I missing something? The polymer-2-starter-kit template form polymer-cli seems to be targeting rc and hardly installs any of UI elements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to upgrade your component dependencies one at a time. And, make sure to read the change logs, and take notice of features that may break.

Comment: I guess, one at a time is what I attempted. Didn't read the change logs though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to Frank R. I have started with polymer-2-starter-kit and kept adding paper elements as needed. Bower did not ask for any resolutions (I did bower cash clean).
Here is my current and working bower:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^2.0.0",
    "webcomponentsjs": "webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#^1.0.0",
    "app-layout": "PolymerElements/app-layout#^2.0.0",
    "app-route": "PolymerElements/app-route#^2.0.0",
    "iron-ajax": "PolymerElements/iron-ajax#^2.0.0",
    "iron-collapse": "PolymerElements/iron-collapse#^2.0.0",
    "iron-form": "PolymerElements/iron-form#^2.0.0",
    "iron-form-element-behavior": "PolymerElements/iron-form-element-behavior#^2.0.0",
    "iron-flex-layout": "PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout#^2.0.0",
    "iron-icon": "PolymerElements/iron-icon#^2.0.0",
    "iron-iconset-svg": "PolymerElements/iron-iconset-svg#^2.0.0",
    "iron-label": "PolymerElements/iron-label#^2.0.0",
    "iron-list": "PolymerElements/iron-list#^2.0.0",
    "iron-media-query": "PolymerElements/iron-media-query#^2.0.0",
    "iron-pages": "PolymerElements/iron-pages#^2.0.0",
    "iron-selector": "PolymerElements/iron-selector#^2.0.0",
    "paper-badge": "PolymerElements/paper-badge#^2.0.0",
    "paper-button": "PolymerElements/paper-button#^2.0.0",
    "paper-checkbox": "PolymerElements/paper-checkbox#^2.0.0",
    "paper-dialog": "PolymerElements/paper-dialog#^2.0.0",
    "paper-dropdown-menu": "PolymerElements/paper-dropdown-menu#^2.0.0",
    "paper-fab": "PolymerElements/paper-fab#^2.0.0",
    "paper-icon-button": "PolymerElements/paper-icon-button#^2.0.0",
    "paper-input": "PolymerElements/paper-input#^2.0.0",
    "paper-item": "PolymerElements/paper-item#^2.0.0",
    "paper-listbox": "PolymerElements/paper-listbox#^2.0.0",
    "paper-toast": "PolymerElements/paper-toast#^2.0.0",
    "paper-tooltip": "PolymerElements/paper-tooltip#^2.0.0",
    "paper-password-input": "^2.1.0",
    "vaadin-upload": "^2.0.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.0.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.6.0"
  },
```